# filter an array of objects based on another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects and I want to filter it with another array so in this example I would expect the object that has id of 3 as a result

```
//the array of objects
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Country: "x",
    industry: "technology",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Country: "y",
    industry: "Data alaysis",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Country: "y",
    industry: "technology",
  },
];

//the filters array
const filters = ["technology", "y"];
```

I've tried to check if those two keys have the value of in the array of objects match with the array of filters like this

```
  const keys = [
    "industry",
    "Country"
  ];

  const search = (array) => {
    return array.filter(
      (item) =>
        keys.some((key) => item[key].includes(filters))
    );
  };
```

but it only works if there's one value in the array so I want it to check on all values in the array

Comment: The question is whether the order of `const filters = ["technology", "y"];` will always match exactly with the indexes of `const keys = ["industry","Country"];` ? You have not taken that important aspect into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Country: "x",
    industry: "technology",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Country: "y",
    industry: "Data analysis",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Country: "y",
    industry: "technology",
  },
];

const filters = ["technology", "y"];

const keys = ["industry", "Country"];

const search = (array) => {
  return array.filter((item) =>
    keys.some(key => filters.includes(item[key]))
  );
};

console.log(search(array));
```